# npm start webpack issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I got mini app in react and trying to start it with npm start - package.json - "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"

All works fine in windows but when trying to start this on Ubuntu console throws an error

/var/www/react_pwa/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:143
                throw new Error("options/query cannot be used with loaders");

I've updated node.js and npm so I thik this might be webpack configuration issue. The file looks like this now

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      query: {
        "presets": [
          "es2015",
          "stage-0",
          "react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "react-hot-loader/babel"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css/,
      loaders: ["style", "css"]
    }]
  }
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What version of webpack are you using? I'm having a similar issue when I change `loader: 'babel'` to `loaders: ['babel']`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `loaders: ['babel']` to `loader: 'babel'` and it should work.

I don't think you can use query with multiple "loaders" because it doesn't know what query to attach to which loader.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing a dependency in your `package.json`.

Have you installed `react-hot-loader`, `css-loader`, `style-loader`, `babel-loader`,`babel-core`, `babel-preset-es2015`,`babel-preset-react`,`babel-preset-stage-0` ?

Try running this command to make sure:

```
npm install --save-dev react-hot-loader css-loader style-loader babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-preset-stage-0
```

Another thing you can do is `ls node_modules` in your windows setup and make sure all dependencies are in your `package.json` so you install them on `npm install`.